How to connect MySQL database to Microsoft copilot studio
I have a Copilot Studio chatbot.
I want to be able to connect a MySQL database to Copilot Studio chatbot to be able to ask questions.
Is there a way to do this or something similar?

you need to create an API to integrate MySQL to chatbot

Possible ways

You Can create action and create a function to convert natural language to SQL query using Azure Functions and Query MySQL DataBase



